# Implementing Branching Conversation Dialogue in C# with XNA

Tags: xna, c#

How could I add logical branching conversation dialogue in `C#` with `XNA`? What I mean by this is a dialogue tree similar to this:

```
If the user is wearing red:
     DisplayText "You're wearing a red shirt!"
Else:
     DisplayText "You're not wearing a red shirt!"
```

The key is that I can't hard-code these logic questions into `C#` itself; it has to be readable from some sort of external file and still executable.

My question is very similar to this question: [How can I implement dialog trees into my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-can-i-implement-dialog-trees-into-my-game)

But my focus is more on how I can actually begin to implement this feature into my game.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with XNA (unless you need help in drawing text on the screen)

Comment: I recommend that you take a look here:
http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2012/GDC2012_Ruskin_Elan_DynamicDialog.pdf

Comment: I'm asking this question in the context of XNA because a particular scripting language (for implementing the dialog tree) might be best for this particular framework.

Comment: I voted to close because that other question DOES provide all the needed information.  The highest answer suggests XML, which is a viable data source in XNA.  The only remaining different part of this question are the implementation details.